# Is it advisable to update sqlite database rapidly from AsyncTask instances? I am getting ANR in the Service

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

This is my scenario:

- **Chat message enters device through websocket in remote Service.**
- **Message  is logged in database table by a new AsyncTask instance.**
- **Message is then sent to Activity that displays it through remote-Service-to-Activity communication.**

After a while I get ANR in the service and then the Service crashes with a SIGABRT or whatever!

I tested under heavy load. (as in chat messages flowing in rapidly, say 1 per second)

My question is this: Could it be that the rapid data inserts into the database in the AsyncTasks..(***I know they perform their tasks in series, no matter how many I use, right?***) caused the ANR that led to the crash?

Thanks!

Comment: how are you executing these AsyncTasks  ..AsyncTask.execute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your code from

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

to

```
new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

it is hard for me to be more specific without seeing your code

Comment: Hmmm thanks..I will try it out and let you know how it goes...my chat server is down and I will have to find a workaround to test this thoroughly....